# Find Line Above or Below in Javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am working on an in-place HTML editor, concentrating on Firefox only right now. I have an element inserted where the cursor should be and also have left and right arrows working, but I can't seem to find a way to find:

1. Start and end of a line for the home and end keys
2. The next line up or down for the up/down arrows.

I see document.elementFromPoint, but this doesn't get me a Range object. The Range object itself seems rather useless when it comes to using pixel positions.

Comment: are you using a TextArea for your HTML editor or using the content-editable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a to create a range for the element under specific pixel position, you can combine document.elementFromPoint() and document.createRange() and Range.selectNodeContents();

The snippet below would highlight the content of an element at (100,200)

```
var elem = document.elementFromPoint(100,200);
var r = document.createRange();
var s = window.getSelection()
r.selectNodeContents(elem);
s.removeAllRanges();
s.addRange(r);
```

I hope this will help you find the final solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'start and end of a line'.  Are you referring to a line of text on the page, regardless of its containing element?  Can you provide a link to your app or an illustrative example page?

IE and Firefox both provide an [element.getClientRects()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getClientRects) method.  However, it only works under certain circumstances and doesn't behave the same from browser to browser.  See [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2008/02/the_cssom_view.html) for [details](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/tests/rectangles.html).

This method will probably not be helpful in many situations.  In the case that you have a P element containing bare text, Firefox returns a collection containing a single element representing the P element.  It doesn't tell you anything about the lines of text it contains.

Most of the in-place editors that I've seen work by clicking on an element to edit it.  The element is then replaced by a textbox/area and associated save/cancel buttons.